# Remove dagger generated classes from Android Studio's global search?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, dagger-2, dagger

It is really irritating. I need more time to find some class because of dagger 2.

Comment: Which search are you talking about? `Command + Shift + O`? If yes, than it's "search everywhere", it should bring everything.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are talking about the generated `MembersInjector` and `Factory` classes:

```
MyClass_MembersInjector.java
MyClass_Factory.java
```

you can prevent these from coming up in the <kbd>Ctr-N</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-O</kbd> dialog by adding them to the ignored files list in `File / Settings / Editor / FileTypes` and adding the appropriate wildcards to the `Ignore files and folders` edittext:

[image: the ignore files and folders dialog in IntelliJ]

`*_MembersInjector.java; *_Factory.java;` will cause most of the generated classes to be ignored:

**Before:**

[image: before applying the settings]

**After:**

[image: after applying the settings]

You can even add `Dagger*.java` to the list if you don't even want to see the generated component (even though this is rather useful for the project).

**Update:**

If you are talking about not having the classes appear in auto-import/auto-complete this is done through `Settings / Editor / General / Auto Import`:

[image: auto import settings dialog in IntelliJ]

Comment: As for 2020 year Dagger 2, you change exceptions line to _Provide.java;*_Factory.java;*_Bind*.java

Comment: @DmitriyPavlukhin Yes `_Provide.java;*_Factory.java;*_Bind*.java` worked thanks for the update

Comment: For [Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/) I use these exceptions: `*_MembersInjector.java; *_Factory.java; *_Providers.java; *_Bindings.java; *_HiltComponents_*.java`

Comment: nice! I've added to this rules suggestions from the https://aednlaxer.medium.com/getting-rid-of-generated-files-in-search-dialog-in-android-studio-ae466a1261a4

Answer (score 19):

David Rawson's answer doesn't help to get rid of not showing `_Factory` classes when performing `Find Usages` on the class name. This is what will be shown:

[image]

This can be resolved with creating a new scope which will disregard generated files.

[image]

[image]

Here's the regex for generated files in `app` module: `!file[app]:build/generated//*`. But you may as well use "Exclude recursively" button locating the directory you want to get rid of.

[image]

Now, change the search scope to newly created:

[image]

And this will be the output:

[image]

No `_Factory` classes. You may as well get rid of classes in test packages, thus only classes from production package will be found.

Comment: That's great. I would even write it as !file:build/generated//* that way it'll remove generated from other modules than app

Comment: How can we filter if it's for instance: Hilt_LoginActivity? It's a generated file from Hilt. Thank you.

Comment: @RedM `Hilt_*.java`

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio Dolphin there is a new option in `Find Usages` dialog, so you can ignore usages in generated code.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio, go to

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Ignored Files and Folders

and add wild cards. Enter apply.

For [Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/), you can add following flags/wildcards `*_MembersInjector.java; *_Factory.java; *_Providers.java; *_Bindings.java; *_HiltComponents_*.java; *_Provide*.java`

Comment: thanks, I'll just add to the list: *_HiltModules.java

Comment: *Hilt*.java is enough