# Hide auto-generated Hilt classes from showing in Find Usage search using Android Studio/Intellij

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a bunch of auto generated Hilt class files showing when I try to find usage of a certain class (cmd + click in Mac). These classes are usually prefixed with Hilt + the class name requesting the hilt generation e.g: Hilt_LoginActivity

[image]

It's kind of annoying. How can I hide it from the find usage? Cheers

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I used an answer from an old similar question about dagger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260687/11276817)

But instead of `*_MembersInjector.java; *_Factory.java;` add `*_MembersInjector.java;*_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java;*_Factory.java;*Factory.java;` in the ignored file types.

Comment: so simple, shame I didn't use it earlier